# How do you work out how long a program will take to run by inspection?

Tags: time, dynamic-programming

I went to a lecture on algorithms the other day, and we were learning about dynamic programming. The lecturer mentioned that to solve fibonacci recursively will take close to exponential time, and doing it in a linear fashion will take quadratic time. How do you work this kind of stuff out just by inspection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only the recursive implementation(with out memoization)
to determine f_n you need to calcualte f_n-1 and f_n-2, similarly
f_n-1 will branch to f_n-2 and f_n-3 and same for f_n-2.
So if there is such branching
and there is no any reuse concept try to count the nodes. It will be >2^n most of the time
this implies **exponential** running time.
But if you use a linear fashion(as you mentioned) it will be **linear** O(n) not even **quadratic**!

But you have to be careful about divide and conquer algorithms like merge sort
although it uses binary division the deepth of the tree will be logn where the number of nodes will become to be **2^logn** *which is equal to* **n**.